# Java Convert TimeZone

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have seen several questions like this but I can't quite get the conversion right. I want to convert a date like the following

**20121116203036Z**

to

**2012-11-16 15:30:36**

I have the following code

```
    dateStringTime.set( year, mon-1 , day, hour, minute, second );

    Date date = dateStringTime.getTime();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

    String output = formatter.format();
    return output;
```

which works but it gives me the below

**2012-11-16 20:30:36**

Any advice on how to get **15** instead of **20**?

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is not formatting 'date', try this:

```
  String output = formatter.format(date);
```

I also notice you are not showing us how you are creating `dateStringTime` which I assumed to be a `Calendar`. I noticed that the `Calendar.getInstance()` method also accepts a `Locale` which might affect the timezone.

My code:

```
    Calendar dateStringTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    //convert 20121116203036Z       
    int year = 2012;
    int mon = 11;
    int day = 16;
    int hour = 20;
    int minute = 30;
    int second = 36;

    dateStringTime.set( year, mon-1 , day, hour, minute, second );

    Date date = dateStringTime.getTime();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

    String output = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println(output);
```

My output:

```
2012-11-16 21:30:36
```

You notice that the hour is 1 hour off? That is because I'm in the Central time zone and the JVM is taking that into account when I ask for 'EST'. It thinks that the original time is in the current timezone.

what happens when you comment out

```
        //formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```

Comment: When I do that I get... 

2012-11-17 01:30:36

Comment: Hint: the code following "convert 20121116203036Z" *isn't doing that*.

Answer (score 1):

TimeZone.[getDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) will give the runtime timezone.
If you will remove the [getRawOffet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset%28%29) value from `date`, you will have the UTC.
one more step is to add/ remove the EST value from from UTC and is done the conversion

Comment: Please avoid manually doing time computations, particularly when there's actually a simple solution that doesn't involve doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're entering the date in the wrong timezone.  When you do this

```
dateStringTime.set(year, month-1 , day, hour, minute, second);
```

you are actually entering the date using your default timezone, which is unlikely in your case to be UTC.  Under the covers, the Java `Date` is represented as UTC, so it will *translate the date/time to UTC* rather than entering directly in UTC.

Basically, it's doing the following sequence of timezone translations:  EST -> UTC -> EST

If you intend to specify a date/time using UTC, you should do this:

```
dateStringTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
dateStringTime.set(year, month-1 , day, hour, minute, second);
```

Then you'll only be going from UTC -> EST and you should get the proper output.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(
    "20121116203036Z" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddHHmmssX" ) 
).toLocalDateTime()
 .toString()
 .replace( "T" , " " )
```

## java.time

The java.time classes built into Java make this easy. Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` & `DateFormat`, now legacy.

```
String input = "20121116203036Z";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddHHmmssX" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): 2012-11-16T20:30:36Z

To get your output you could define a custom `DateTimeFormatter`. A lazier way is to convert to a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) just to lose the `Z` on the end, which indicates the offset-from-UTC (`Z` is short for `Zulu` and means UTC). Then use `toString` to generate a string in ISO 8601 format except replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
String output = odt.toLocalDateTime().toString().replace( "T" , " " );
```

> 2012-11-16 20:30:36

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/mB8b5L).

## ISO 8601

I suggest rather than using your format for such date-time values, instead use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. The usual format for such a value is `2016-11-16T02:45:02Z`. Note the `T` in the middle separating year-month-day from hour-minute-second. Alternatively, the standard allows minimizing the use of separators, considered the “basic” version: `20161116T024502Z` but retains the `T` in the middle.

The java.time classes can parse and generate the expanded versions but not the basic version.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).